# how to get youtube video with filtering only food related videos?

Tags: video, youtube

I have a link for youtube like 
[https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={apikey}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=7&type=video&q='.$search](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=%7Bapikey%7D&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=7&type=video&q='.$search)

where $search gives the search key

what i want to do is filter videos related to food only adding '&topicId=/m/02wbm'
to query didnt suffice to my desire
any idea how i can get only related videos?